# Name of Curve formed by these Rectangles

Tags: geometry, curves

All of these rectangles have the same surface area (3600 pixels in MS Paint):

[image]

```
10 x 360 
24 x 150     
30 x 120     
40 x 90     
60 x 60     
90 x 40     
120 x 30     
150 x 24     
360 x 10
```

- What is the name of the curve being formed?
- Is there a way to model it with a function?
- Is there a significance of the curve or function, or is it just a
  byproduct of me doodling in MS Paint?

I have a hunch that the curve steepness is independent of the actual surface area I used -- that I could superimpose extra rectangles of 1,000 unit surface area over this and the curves formed would be mathematically similar, but I am having trouble proving this.

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't it just be "area". Can a two-dimensional object have a surface area?

Comment: @StevenGregory You're probably right.

Comment: @StevenGregory I would argue that 2D objects *are* surfaces and it is correct, if redundant, to speak of surface areas in this case. But we're splitting hairs.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio Yes. You are right on both counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out, area $x\times y = A$ is a constant means, the curve traced by the upper right corner of the rectangles is:
\begin{equation}
y = \frac{A}{x} 
\end{equation}
As per the steepness, it follows immediately that it is proportional to the area $A$. This kind of function in which a quantity is inversely proportional to another is ubiquitous in science. Think of pairs of quantities such as frequency/period, current/resistance, time/velocity.

Answer (score 6):

$xy = 3600$ is a hyperbola, since for each row the $x$ value and the $y$ value have a product of $3600$.